# My-sql insert Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'client_requests' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql

I get this error when trying insert data to table. Here is my query

```
INSERT INTO client_requests(client_price_plan_id, request) VALUES
(
(SELECT @client_price_client_price_plans.id FROM client_price_plans 
WHERE client_id = 1),
(SELECT COUNT(client_requests.id) FROM client_requests 
JOIN client_price_plans
ON client_price_plans.client_id = 1
)+1
)
```

Where is my wrong. Please help me

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/45494/798677

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change `FROM client_requests` to `FROM client_requests c`